# Where is the default asp.net web application/database stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have created a WCF service that is hosted within a web application. I want to add authorization to the service. Right now it uses a hardcoded username/password from a custom username password provider. What I am attempting to do is use the database that is by default in the web application to store users.

I went to the Web application configuration page and added a few users. So this means it must be going into a database. Where exactly is this stored? Or more precisely how exactly can I get the connection details for it? With the custom service I should be able to check against any DB with just some validation code and no other changes made to it, so could anyone show me an example of authorization through a DB in C#?

Answer (score 1):

The databse is usually stored on you App_Data folder of you application 
since you are using WCF [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) is the tutorial for you to implement a custom authentication provider for wcf.